# Properly detecting mysql higher than 5 on PHP 5.5 with mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd

My application is using the following code to detect mysql higher than 5. It works well with PHP 5.2, 5.3 and 5.4.

The trouble is with PHP 5.5 which uses mysqlnd by default so the script reports mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 40933630edef551dfaca71298a83fad8d03d62d4 $ and cannot detect MySQL properly. I need to make an exception for such version, but I don't know how to.

```
 echo "<mysql>";
    if(key_exists('mysql', $phpinfo))
    {
        if(key_exists('Client API version', $phpinfo['mysql']))
        {
            $t=explode(".", $phpinfo['mysql']['Client API version']);
            if($t[0]>=5)
                $ok=1;
        else
                $ok=0;
            echo "<val>{$phpinfo['mysql']['Client API version']}</val><ok>$ok</ok>";
        }
        else
           echo "<val></val><ok>0</ok>";
    }
    else
        echo "<val></val><ok>0</ok>";
    echo "</mysql>\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `mysql` in 5.5. It is deprecated.

#### Deprecation of mysql_ functions

> PHP functions that start with `mysql_` have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead.

Anyway, use mysqli (which you seem to have in your question tags)

The phpinfo key is: `$phpinfo['mysqli']['Client API header version']` rather than `$phpinfo['mysql']['Client API version']`.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this SQL command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Will show something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. This is what I was looking for after installing XAMPP